# How to display local images

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image

Working on a ASP.Net MVC project, I've got a page that allows users to upload their own picture. On the database, it is stored a file path, such as `C:\zm\zemanel.jpg`

After some research, it seems that browsers can't access the local machine and for that reason, if I have this:

`<img src="C:\zm\zemanel.jpg"/>`

The image isn't displayed. Note that it is still in development, the path leads to my machine (localhost).

What is the best solution for the user to select an image, have its path stored in the database, and the image to be displayed?

Can the image be included in the project dynamically? Say for example, in the `Images` folder?
Because images stored in a project folder are displayed normally.

Comment: The usual solution is to really upload the image file and store it either on your server on in a service like imgur.com. Storing the user's path is useless.

Comment: This being said this might work : `<img src="file:///C:/zm/zemanel.jpg"/>`. But that's really not what anybody would call "upload".

Comment: I've already tried that and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to keep that image for future use (saving projects, etc).  So sorry if it's overly complex for what you are asking.

I would think that the easiest way to handle this is to just use an input tag.  With that tag you can use certain attributes to select a type of file to show in the client dialog, example[[Example]](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept):

```
//accept tag may not work with older versions of IE
//This shows how to open a client side dialog which defaults to an 'image' filetype.
<input type="file" accept="image/*"></input>
```

As mentioned by others, you would then upload the file, manipulate it (create a thumbnail or whatnot) then insert the image to the page using either a page refresh or javascript to call an ajax request and insert the image.

Any functionality beyond that you'll probably need a Java applet or custom control, which to me seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src="file://c:\zm\zemanel.jpg" />
```